# Why is vim not indenting two spaces for html?

Tags: html, vim

So I am trying to set up my vimrc for python and web development. This is what my vimrc looks like.

```
"--------------vundle------------------------
set nocompatible
filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

"add plugins here
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'itchyny/lightline.vim'

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
"------------------end of vundle-------------------

"--------------python development-----------------
"PEP8 python indentation and formatting
au BufNewFile,BufREad *.py
    \ set tabstop=4
    \ set softtabstop=4
    \ set shiftwidth=4
    \ set textwidth=79
    \ set expandtab
    \ set autoindent
    \set fileformat=unix

let python_highlight_all=1
syntax on

"---------------web development------------------
"basic tab spacing for html, css and js
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.js, *.html, *.css
    \ set tabstop=2
    \set softtabstop=2
    \set shiftwidth=2
```

However when I open or create an html file it indents 8 spaces rather than 2. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check where the indent options were set via

```
:verbose setlocal ts? sts? sw? et?
```

I believe in your case, the problem is with the list of patterns in your `:autocmd`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.js, *.html, *.css
```

There must not be a whitespace between the patterns:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.js,*.html,*.css
```

See `:help autocmd-patterns`; it talks about *comma-separated list*, and the example there also doesn't have whitespace.

#### alternative approaches

By encoding the file patterns for the various languages, you're duplicating the built-in *filetype detection*.

I would recommend to put these `:setlocal` commands into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim` (and so on. This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`; use of the *after* directory allows you to override any default filetype settings done by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/html.vim`.)

Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType {filetype\} ...` directly in your `~/.vimrc`. This would at least avoid the duplication of file patterns, but tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations.

Comment: Thanks! It appears the space between patterns was the issue. I will definitely look into the suggestions you had for structuring my files.

Comment: Having to add softtabstop as well saved me, as tabstop was the issue for me. Indenting with > was giving me two spaces, but tab was giving me 4 despite `autocmd FileType html setlocal shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2`